# Need help on XCode: Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (WebView)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new in XCode and I'm trying to create a simple Webview that displays www.google.com website

But the Code does not RUN. I got an Error: **Threat1: Signal SIGATBRT**

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var WebView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "www.google.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        WebView.load(request)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

> Questions Update

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { // <- The Error Pointing Here!!! -> Threat1: Signal SIGABRT



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

> Output Text

```
2020-01-16 09:58:27.127224+0200 wvApp2[6306:366786] -[__NSArrayM loadRequest:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001f0c3c0
2020-01-16 09:59:21.186755+0200 wvApp2[6306:366786] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM loadRequest:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001f0c3c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c91fd4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c75c4c ___forwarding___ + 1436
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c77f78 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   wvApp2                              0x00000001038677ea $s6wvApp214ViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyF + 890
    6   wvApp2                              0x0000000103867a8b $s6wvApp214ViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyFTo + 43
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a0ef01 -[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 83
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a13e5a -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1084
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a14277 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480ca3cf -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 150
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480c9ac0 -[UIWindow _updateLayerOrderingAndSetLayerHidden:actionBlock:] + 232
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480cab43 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 362
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480ddef1 -[UIWindow _mainQueue_makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff482e9431 -[UIWindowScene _makeKeyAndVisibleIfNeeded] + 202
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4761d445 +[UIScene _sceneForFBSScene:create:withSession:connectionOptions:] + 1405
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4808f170 -[UIApplication _connectUISceneFromFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 1018
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4808f4b2 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 304
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47bfa7f5 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365d6165 -[FBSSceneImpl _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 442
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365fc4d8 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.154 + 102
    21  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365e0c45 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 220
    22  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365fc169 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 355
    23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103b91d48 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103b94cb9 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 300
    25  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff3662237e __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    26  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff3662206c -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 441
    27  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff3662257b -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 22
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd4471 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd439c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd3bcc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bce87f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bce066 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    33  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff384c0bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    34  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48092d4d UIApplicationMain + 1621
    35  wvApp2                              0x00000001038689bb main + 75
    36  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5227ec25 start + 1
    37  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

This is the Output text from All Output Window. I think this will help to clear out all misunderstandings on this question. This output is from the Run of the app till the exception.

> Recent Issues

Showing Recent Issues

Build target wvApp2 of project wvApp2 with configuration Debug

```
CompileStoryboard /Users/admin/DevSource/wvApp2/wvApp2/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard (in target 'wvApp2' from project 'wvApp2')
    cd /Users/admin/DevSource/wvApp2
    export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --module wvApp2 --output-partial-info-plist /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wvApp2-ehhbosgmbdwuucejiweipdfuqjzt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/wvApp2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/wvApp2.build/Base.lproj/Main-SBPartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --minimum-deployment-target 13.2 --output-format human-readable-text --compilation-directory /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wvApp2-ehhbosgmbdwuucejiweipdfuqjzt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/wvApp2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/wvApp2.build/Base.lproj /Users/admin/DevSource/wvApp2/wvApp2/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard

/* com.apple.ibtool.document.warnings */
/Users/admin/DevSource/wvApp2/wvApp2/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:Bvy-8R-dSa: warning: UIWebView is deprecated since iOS 12.0 [7]
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, 
How can I solve this? Anyone answer is welcome.

Comment: Crashes like yours always point to the `AppDelegate`.  You can simple remove your updated AppDelegate code, but provide the stack trace from the output window, where it reads something like "Unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping..." and all that stuff

Comment: Set the Exception Breakpoint. If it states famous *unexpected found `nil`* then the outlet is not connected.

Comment: @vadian The ~request` appears to be nil, I set the Breakpoint on, then by debugging, request return ~nil~. how to solve it?

Comment: A request for `www.google.com` cannot be `nil`. If the URL is more complex then you left out a pretty crucial information.

Comment: The truth is that I refer to this link, but I cant get it properly. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KO0_-nxDvHU

Comment: Just send us the output from the output window (not as screenshot, but as text)

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I have just updated my question with the output of my app. I hope it will help.

Comment: Seems you have some kind of array instead of WebView... Please add the following code before you call `webView.load`: `let theType =  String(describing: type(of: webView));  print(theType)` and show us what is put out.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen It's Display the Very Same Error with the very same Output. I think I have to start over then run it again.

Comment: The connection of the outlet in Interface Builder is wrong. According to the stack trace `WebView` — by the way please name properties with starting lowercase letter — is connected to an array.

Comment: #vadian that was already edited. Thanks. I got a new update @Andreas, Please Take a look.

Comment: So your app crashes before `let theType = String(describing: type(of: webView)); print(theType)` is executed? This seems strange to me. As #vadian said, it seems you initally connected your outlet to an `@IBOutletCollection`, but then changed the code just to `@IBOutlet` without re-establishing the link from the storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should better let variables start with a *lowercase* letter (and types with a *uppercase*). This is the kind-of-convetion in Swift (and Java and C++ and C and almost any other programming language except C#):

```
 @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
```

(change this using *refactor* in Xcode, to sync the storyboard/xib)

Then, don't use explicit unwrapping, better use `if let`:

```
if let url = URL(string: "www.google.com") {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(request)
}
```

To your exception: The only other thing (besides that the explicit `url!` unwrapping could fail) might be that the outlet `webView` is nil. You could also check this:

```
if (webView == nil) {
    print ("Ooops")
}
```

If it's nil, check the connections from the storyboard/xib.

Comment: #Anreas, Thanks for your answer, But I'm getting now an error under ~webview.load(request)~  that says: ~Use of unresolved identifier 'request'~. What's that mean?

Comment: Take a look of the curly braces. I think you put `webView.load(request)` outside of the `if let` block, where the `request` is being defined. It needs to be on the same level.

Comment: #Andreas I have add a Hint, I have fix accordingly to what you have instructed me. But when I debug the app, I'm getting the error pointed as described above. what can it be?

Comment: See my comment on on your question. In those exception cases, Xcode will almost always point to the AppDelegate and not to the falty code

Comment: Your approach was very helpful. After recreating new projects and do some testing, the problem was laying on the version and the review was depreciated on IOS12. And also, the connection of the outlet in Interface Builder is wrong, I had to think that too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you **import webKit framework** in your project target.

Target -> General -> Linked Framework and Libraries -> click on the + -> add the webKit.framwork

If you have done that and it's still not working please show more of the error message you are getting.

Also on a side note for naming convention you should not start class properties with uppercase.

Leading uppercase names are reserved for classes, this way you will always know if the code is referring to a class or a property. So in your case:

```
// @IBOutlet var WebView: WKWebView! change this to
@IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
```

Comment: If nobody messed with the LLVM-settings in Xcode, nowadays frameworks will automatically be linked when imported.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasOetjen, wasn't aware of this. That's pretty neat!